# dojox.grid.DataGrid New Item at the top

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I was using this example.

[Dojo Official Grid Test](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/checkout/dojox/grid/tests/test_edit_dijit.html)

Which adds new item at the bottom of the existing records.

I want to know, how can I have the new items appear at the top instead of at the bottom, which seems to be default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The entries in that DataGrid are sorted ascendingly by their ID. You can set how the elements are sorted by either sorting manually:

```
grid.setSortIndex(1, false); //first column, not ascending
```

Or by setting `sortInfo`:

```
grid.setSortInfo(-1); //first column descending.
```

See their [documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/grid/DataGrid) and [this summary](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#datagrid-object-functions).

Answer (score 1):

The official test example used old style dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore as store, and that kind of store only have newItem(), deleteItem(), save() APIS, no insertItem API, so it is hard to put new items at the top.

My suggestion is that you can try using new type data store dojo.store.Memory, this new store has easy API to change data   store.setData(yourdataArray), you can modify your underline yourdataArray (it is just a javscript array) as you want. After you set your new data to store, try refresh grid.

See [document at here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/store_driven_grid/)